# NGINX with ownCloud + other sites

Tags: pi-2, web-server

I have my owncloud subdomain installed successfuly but when trying to have other websites (sub domains) i allways get 502 Bad Gateway.

I've changed php7.0-fpm listen to 127.0.0.1:9000 and this caused owncloud to work and the others stoped working, how can I have both configurations ?

ownCloud configuration:

```
upstream php-handler {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.com;

    # enforce https
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.xxx.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/owncloud_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/owncloud_cert.key;

    # Add headers to serve security related headers
    # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this topic first.
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;

    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/www/owncloud/;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    location = /.well-known/carddav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
    }
    location = /.well-known/caldav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        default_type "text/plain";
        allow all;
    }

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
    gzip off;

    # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
    # This module is currently not supported.
    #pagespeed off;

    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php$uri;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
        return 404;
    }
    location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+|core/templates/40[34])\.php(?:$|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true; #Avoid sending the security headers twice
        fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
        fastcgi_pass php-handler;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_request_buffering off; #Available since NGINX 1.7.11
    }

    location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.php;
    }

    # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
    # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=15778463";
        # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to have those duplicated to the ones above)
        # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this topic first.
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
        add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
        # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

other: (this one retrieves 502 error)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.com;
    # enforce https
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/raspberry_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/raspberry_cert.key;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_param PATH_TO_FRAMEWORKS /var/www/frameworks/;
        #fastcgi_param CORE_TYPE frameworks;
        #fastcgi_param IS_DEV true;
        #include fastcgi_params;
    }

    #location = /favicon.ico {
    #    log_not_found off;
    #    access_log off;
    #}

    #location = /robots.txt {
    #    allow all;
    #    log_not_found off;
    #    access_log off;
    #}

    #location ~ /\. {
    #    deny all;
    #}

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

I've searched and tried a lot of things, but no success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution in the default nginx configuration file, I just had to separete how the php7.0 would work with both onecloud and others.

This was made by pointing php7.0 to 127.0.0.1:9000 and others to php7.0 socket.